# how to read and modify fstab in python?

Tags: configuration, python

I want to automatically configure my `fstab` in `python` by running a script. I thought of using `ConfigParser` in `python`, but I am unable to use it properly.

Comment: I voted to migrate this to StackOverflow. You may be speaking about editing a particular file on a *nix OS, but your asking about doing so in a programming language (which means, to me, that the answer is more concerned with programming than with *nix).

Comment: @HalosGhost shell programming is often about editing a particular file and it is always in some programming language, as long as it is for U&L administrative purposes, I don't think we should move all of those questions.

Comment: @Anthon, shells are often *nix specific. This isn't a shell programming question, it's a Python question. But, I don't have the ability to migrate; it was just a vote.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can using [fstab](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fstab) module.

Its documentation [here](http://python-fstab.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.4-0ubuntu1/fstab_8py-source.html).

Example:

```
fstab = Fstab()

for entry in fstab.entries:
    pprint.pprint(entry)
```

Answer (score 5):

This will not work because `/etc/fstab` file doesn't conform to the format the ConfigParser supports.

As `man 5 fstab` indicates, the `/etc/fstab` file is a whitespace separated file with 6 columns. The Python [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) is a library for Parsing files commonly known as `.ini` files that, simplified, consist of sections that contain key/value pairs:

```
 [section_name1]
 key1 = value1
 key2 = value2
 [section_name2]
 key3 = value3
```

Parsing the `fstab` file yourself is relatively easy. Just copy all the comment lines (those with first non-whitespace character '#') and split the other lines using `.split()` to the 6 fields. I use that to rearrange my `fstab` file to be only 79 columns.